# Order List in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a table called `Table1` in SQL with `A`, `B`, `C` as columns and `A` is primary key whereas `C` is FK to same table.

I need to generate the list so that it will be in the following order: first it will take object with one PK and then take objects where that PK is pointing at as FK.

I am trying to convert below query in Linq to generate a list:

```
select A,B,C from Table1 where C in (select A from Table1) order by 3
```

Am I going correct? if not then what is the possible way?

Comment: where is linq query, i can see just sql query here

Comment: Looks like you need a recursive query: take the first row, then take a row that points to the previous row, then take a row that points to the previous row, etc... I think you'll need to dig into "raw" SQL for that (take a look at recursive common table expressions).

Comment: @Selman22 that's the problem. I am not able to generate one.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic How do i do that in C#?

Comment: @PratikGaikwad You can use ADO.NET to execute the recursive query directly.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic I am using DBML diagram to generate my db in project so that I can use LINQ to SQL structure. I need to use that only.

Comment: People should mention in comment why they downvote que, here Pratik clearly mention what exactly he wants.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad You can mix LINQ and "raw" SQL. Take a look at [DataContext.ExecuteQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery(v=vs.110).aspx). You can also supply an existing ADO.NET connection when you create a LINQ to SQL DataContext and continue to issue queries directly against the ADO.NET connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var result =   (from x in Table1
    from y in Table1
    where x.C == y.A
    order by x.B
    select new { A = x.A, B=x.B,C=x.C}).ToList();
```